# Serialize class with structs of same type name

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to XML serialize a class that contains two structs with the same name:

```
public class MyClass 
{
  public System.Windows.Size WSize = new System.Windows.Size();
  public System.Drawing.Size DSize = new Size.Drawing.Size();
}
```

The resulting error:

```
Types 'System.Drawing.Size' and 'System.Windows.Size' both use the XML type name, 
'Size', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or 
namespace for the type.
```

Everything I've found so far involves decorating the `Type` with an XML attribute.  I can't directly decorate either struct since they are not my code.

I feel like I'm missing something easy here...Is there an XML attribute that I can apply to the fields?

**EDIT**
I've added answer using a couple surrogate properties.  I'm not happy with that particular implementation since it leaves public properties hanging out.

I've also considered `DataContractSerialization` but I'm hesitant to take that next step quite yet.  Anyone else have something they can suggest?

**EDIT 2**
There may have been some confusion in my wording.  I can modify and decorate `MyClass`, `WSize` and `DSize`. However, perhaps obviously, I cannot modify `System.Windows.Size` or `System.Drawing.Size`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by proxy with custom XML serialization, I created this fully working example, although there is a lot of error checking to be done its a place to start.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public System.Windows.Size WSize = new System.Windows.Size();
    public System.Drawing.Size DSize = new System.Drawing.Size();
}

public class MyClassProxy : MyClass, IXmlSerializable
{
    public new System.Windows.Size WSize { get { return base.WSize; } set { base.WSize = value; } }
    public new System.Drawing.Size DSize { get { return base.DSize; } set { base.DSize = value; } }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        string wheight = reader["height"];
        string wwidth = reader["width"];
        int w, h;
        w = int.Parse(wwidth);
        h = int.Parse(wheight);
        WSize = new Size(w, h);
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        string dheight = reader["height"];
        string dwidth = reader["width"];
        w = int.Parse(dwidth);
        h = int.Parse(dheight);
        DSize = new System.Drawing.Size(w, h);
    }

    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("MyClassProxy");
        writer.WriteStartElement("WSize");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("height", WSize.Height.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("width", WSize.Width.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("DSize");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("height", DSize.Height.ToString());
        writer.WriteAttributeString("width", DSize.Width.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClassProxy p = new MyClassProxy();
        p.DSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
        p.WSize = new Size(400, 400);

        string xml = "";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            System.Xml.XmlWriter wr = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(sw);
            p.WriteXml(wr);
            wr.Close();
            xml = sw.ToString();
        }

        MyClassProxy p2 = new MyClassProxy();

        using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            System.Xml.XmlReader r = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(sr);
            p2.ReadXml(r);
        }

        MyClass baseClass = (MyClass)p2;

        Print(baseClass);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Print(MyClass c)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.DSize.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(c.WSize.ToString());
    }


}
```

Comment: Yuck...This would be a nightmare to implement on my huge class.   I'll mark this as the answer if I can't get anything else.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, if you can modify MyClass then just put the serialization code there and don't use the proxy, I thought you couldn't modify MyClass to decorate it...

Comment: Yes, I can modify `MyClass`, I cannot modify the `Size` structs.  So perhaps your solution is a bit more tenable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility that I'm not terribly happy with (not very clean):

```
public class MyClass 
{
  public System.Windows.Size WSize = new System.Windows.Size();

  [XmlIgnore]
  public System.Drawing.Size DSize = new Size();

  public int DSizeWidthForSerialization
  {
    get
    {
      return DSize.Width;
    }
    set
    {
      DSize.Width = value;
    }
  }
  public int DSizeHeightForSerialization
  {
    get
    {
      return DSize.Height;
    }
    set
    {
      DSize.Height = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new class to house `System.Drawing.Size`.  Within that new class I created implicit operators and handled some of the constructors.  This allowed me to serialize and not have to change any existing code:

```
public class MyClass 
{
  public System.Windows.Size WSize = new System.Windows.Size();
  public MyDrawingSize DSize = new System.Drawing.Size();

  public class MyDrawingSize
  {
    public int Height, Width;

    public MyDrawingSize() { } //Needed for deserialization
    public MyDrawingSize(int width, int height)
    {
      Width = width;
      Height = height;
    }
    public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Size(MyDrawingSize size)
    {
      return new System.Drawing.Size(size.Width, size.Height);
    }
    public static implicit operator MyDrawingSize(System.Drawing.Size size)
    {
      return new MyDrawingSize() { Width = size.Width, Height = size.Height };
    }

  }
}
```